# Is it grammatically correct to say "Let's go to the picture."

Tags: grammar, british-english

Is it grammatically correct to say **"Let's go to the picture"**.
Please justify the reason.

Comment: *Pictures* (when it means *movie*) was originally short for *moving pictures*, so for this meaning we always use the plural form, even though we rarely say *moving pictures* these days.

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatically correct, but needs a very specific context to be semantically appropriate: there is one picture in conversational context, and the speaker suggests to move towards it.

If you meant to invite someone to see a movie, "go to the pictures" (plural) would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! @Amadan

Comment: i think "let's watch  a movie/cinema" would be appropriate

Comment: @etl_devs Yes, if we completely ignore the question wording and the British tag. “Go to the pictures” is (admittedly somewhat older) idiom for visiting a cinema, equivalent in meaning to the American “go to the movies”; but “go to the picture” is not. (Also, “let’s watch a cinema” has a very different meaning than “let’s watch a movie”.)

Comment: oh this British, US war over everything. But i think its important to simply things rather then overcomplicate simple wordings , I don't see a purpose of these words apart from confusing someone